# Cannot build spark-cassandra-connector from source

Tags: cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to install the Spark-Cassandra Connector but I get an error that I'm not able to solve.
I have Cassandra 3.11.2 and Spark 2.3.0 installed and running well.

Here what I'm doing:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector.git
$ cd spark-cassandra-connector
$ sbt/sbt assembly
$ $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --jars ~/spark-cassandra-connector/spark-cassandraconnector/target/scala-2.10/connector-assembly-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

In scala prompt

```
scala> sc.stop
scala> import com.datastax.spark.connector._
```

After this command I get:

```
<console>:23: error: object datastax is not a member of package com
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
```

May someone tell me the steps to solve it?

Comment: Why do you need to compile it yourself, instead of using it like this:
`spark-shell --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.0.7` ? Plus, take into account that Spark Cassandra connector isn't compatible with 2.3.0 yet

Comment: I was just following a tutorial to install the connector, because I've made e vmware image with Cassandra 3.11 and Spark 2.3 to learn them. Thank you.

Comment: It's better to pull officially released version...

Comment: Just follow the "Quick Start" document